# Ruby idiom for determining if an index is in range of a given array?

Tags: ruby

I have an integer value `i` and an array `list`. I want to determine whether `i` is a valid index value on `list`.

Obviously I can do something like:

```
if i >= 0 && i < list.length 
    # Do something with list[i]... 
end
```

However, is there a better Ruby idiom for doing an "is array index valid" check?

Comment: There's another way of writing the same check, `i.between?(0, list.length-1)`

Comment: ...or `(0..list.length-1).cover?(i)` or `(0...list.length).cover?(i)`. There is no definitive answer, however. At heart, you are asking for an opinion.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: and maybe twenty more :)

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Maybe you are approaching the underlying problem in a non-idiomatic way.

Comment: As an aside negative numbers can technically be "in range" given that ruby will work backwards e.g. `list[-1] == list.last`.

Comment: @stefan I encountered this while working on https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/23, which calls for implementing a virtual machine which must exit when the instruction pointer becomes outside of the range of its instruction set.

Comment: @JonSchneider could be a good fit for [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Array.html#method-i-fetch) – when given a block, it will run that block if the index is out of bounds.

Comment: ...and if the array `a` is guaranteed to not contain `nil`, `a[i]` returns `nil` if and only if `i` is out-of-bounds (recognising that sufficiently-large  negative values `i` are valid). I'm coming around to thinking @Stefan's suggestion of using `fetch` is best of the options proposed so far, as it permits the array to contain a `nil` value and permits valid negative values of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

> I encountered this while working on [adventofcode.com/2015/day/23](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/23), which calls for implementing a virtual machine which must exit when the instruction pointer becomes outside of the range of its instruction set.

The virtual machine allows the instruction pointer to be incremented and decremented, so we have to assume that it can also be negative.

In Ruby, negative array indices count from the array's end with `-1` being the last element, e.g.:

```
ary = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

ary[-1] #=> "baz"
ary[-2] #=> "bar"
ary[-3] #=> "foo"
```

Which means any index from `-3` to `2` is considered to be within `ary`'s bounds.

To exclude negative values, you have to build your own check. I would probably use a [range](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Range.html) to represent the bounds: (using `...` instead of `..` makes it exclude the end)

```
bounds = 0...ary.size
```

You can now process the instructions in a loop and check your instruction pointer via [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
instructions = <<EOD.split("\n")
inc a
jio a, +2
tpl a
inc a
EOD

bounds = 0...instructions.size
ip = 0

while bounds.include?(ip)
  ins = instructions[ip]

  # do something with ins

  ip += 1
end
```

Internally, it checks for `bound.begin <= ip` and `ip < bounds.end`.